# If $N = 2^{(2^2)}$, find real $x$ such that $N^{N^N}=2^{(2^x)}$. Understanding the solution.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Harvard-MIT Math Tournament 2019 Algebra Problem:

> Let $N = 2^{(2^2)}$ and $x$ be a real number such that $N^{N^N}=2^{(2^{x})}$. Find $x$.

Solution:
$$N^{(N^N)}=16^{16^{16}} = 2^{4\cdot2^{^{4\cdot2^{{4}}}}} = 2^{2^{2^{6}+2}} = 2^{2^{66}}$$

I don't understand how to get from (the previous step) $2^{4\cdot2^{^{4\cdot2^{{4}}}}}$ to (the final answer) $2^{2^{66}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to organize the steps differently. We have
$$
N^{N^N} = (2^4)^{N^N} = 2^{4 \cdot N^{N}}.
$$
Now, we can write
$$
N^N = (2^4)^{2^4} = 2^{4 \cdot 2^4} = 2^{2^6} = 2^{64},
$$
and note that
$$
4 \cdot N^{N} = 2^2 \cdot 2^{64} = 2^{66}.
$$
Finally, this means that
$$
N^{N^N} = 2^{4 \cdot N^N} = 2^{2^{66}}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$(2^4)^{2^4} = 2^{4\times 2^4} = 2^{2^6}$$

$$(2^4)^{(2^4)^{2^4}}=(2^4)^{2^{2^6}}=2^{4\times 2^{2^6}}=2^{2^2 \times 2^{64}}=2^{2^{66}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Noting that $N=16$ the equation becomes
$$
16^{16^{16}}=2^{2^x}
$$
Taking the $\log_2$ of both sides yields
$$
\overbrace{\ 4\cdot16^{16}\ }^{2^{66}}=2^x
$$
Thus, taking $\log_2$ again,
$$
x=66
$$

Answer (score -1):

To my eye, the difficulty lies in the typography: It's hard to see which superscripts are at what level.* I recommend taking logarithms instead.  Using the abbreviation $\lg$ for $\log_2$, we have

$$\begin{align}
x&=\lg(\lg(2^{2^x}))\\
&=\lg(\lg(N^{N^N}))\\
&=\lg(N^N\lg(N))\\
&=\lg(N^N)+\lg(\lg(N))\\
&=N\lg(N)+\lg(\lg(N))\\
&=16\lg(16)+\lg(\lg(16))\\
&=16\cdot4+\lg(4)\\
&=64+2\\
&=66
\end{align}$$

*In fact there is a typo in the OP's display: "2^{4\cdot^{2^{4\cdot^{2^{4}}}}}" should be "2^{4\cdot{2^{4\cdot{2^{4}}}}}" (without the spurious ^'s after the \cdot's), i.e

$$2^{4\cdot{2^{4\cdot{2^{4}}}}}\qquad\text{instead of}\qquad2^{4\cdot^{2^{4\cdot^{2^{4}}}}}$$

but even when TeXed correctly, I find it hard to see which superscript is at which level.